# Batch command to check if FTP connection is successful

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I am writing a batch command to send data via FTP. Before sending the actual data I need to find if the FTP server is active/running. How do I check that in batch command?

The server responds with "220 server ready" message when it is connected.

Comment: Maybe you can use `ftp -s:ftpscript.txt` and thus avoid the need to check if the server is running?

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
YourFTPCommand | find /i /v "220 server ready" && goto :ServerNotReady
```

Explanation:

1. Pipe the output of your FTP command to FIND
2. Do a case insensitive (/i) search for output that does not contain (/v) the string "220 server ready"
3. Go to someplace if such a string is found (&&)

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there's a reliable way to do this with Windows `ftp.exe`.

It blindly keeps running the commands, no matter if connection or previous commands succeeded.

It won't even report the result via exit code.

All you can do is to parse the `ftp.exe` output.

---

You should better use a 3rd-party FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) you can use:

```
@echo off

winscp.com /log=ftp.log /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@example.com/" ^
    "put c:\local\path\file.txt" ^
    "exit"
```

If connection (the [`open`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) command) fails, WinSCP won't execute the following commands (the [`put`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put)).

See also [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP FTP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*