# Batch File FTP attempt for password/authentication multiple times using ERRORLEVEL loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, error-handling, ftp, errorlevel

I can't try to reconnect with a different password after authentication failed. `ERRORLEVEL` seems to not be working in my code. I have no clue what's going wrong. The code is in batch file on Windows 10.

```
@echo off

echo use USERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo PASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat


ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat files.000webhost.com

if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 (
   goto TEST
)

:TEST
echo user USERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo DIFFERENTPASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo prompt>>ftpcmd.dat
echo cd Test>>ftpcmd.dat
echo mput FILE PATH>> ftpcmd.dat

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat FTPTHING
```

Answer (score 1):

The Windows `ftp.exe` always returns 0, no matter what.

All you can possibly do, is to parse its output and look for errors. But that's pretty unreliable.

If you want to take this approach anyway, see

- [how to capture error conditions in windows ftp scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31442020/850848) or
- [Batch command to check if FTP connection is successful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31405011/850848).

---

Though, you better use some better FTP client. Sooner or later you will run into troubles with the `ftp.exe` anyway, as it does not support an encryption, the passive mode or recursive transfers, among many other limitations.

If you are familiar with PowerShell, use the `FtpWebRequest` or `WebClient` from a Powershell script. There are numerous examples here, for example [Upload files with FTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867385/850848).

---

If not, use some 3rd party command-line FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), your batch file may look like:

```
@echo off
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=script.log /command ^
  "open ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftp.example.com/" ^
  "put C:\LOCAL\FILE /REMOTE/PATH/" ^
  "exit"

if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  winscp.com /ini=nul /log=script2.log /command ^
    "open ftp://USERNAME:DIFFERENTPASSWORD@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "put C:\LOCAL\FILE /REMOTE/PATH/" ^
    "exit"
)
```

References:

- [Automate file transfers to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [How do I know that script completed successfully?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_result);
- [Guide to converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP SFTP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

[WinSCP can also be used from PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell), if you want even more robust implementation.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*